# How can I get connected storage devices and information about those on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to do the following:

1. Get a list of physical storage devices connected to the PC
2. For each of these devices, query information: display name, drive letter, storage capacity, free storage capacity and, if possible, a device type (SD Card, Phone etc.)

For me, it seems like there were many ways to achieve the first goal (list of devices), for example [`IPortableDeviceManager::GetDevices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/portabledeviceapi/nf-portabledeviceapi-iportabledevicemanager-getdevices) or the volume management functions in [fileapi.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/). But since I've never used the winapi before, I'm unable to determine which API I should use.

Comment: You can use everything in WinRT's `Windows.Devices.Enumeration` Namespace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration with C++/WinRT for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you, this is what I was looking for! Is there a way to get the drive letter with `DeviceInformation`

Comment: driver letters can be determined from volumes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumepathnamesforvolumenamew